# how to handle values other than json in fetch api call

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

```
I want to send json data to API AND GET A STRING VALUE WILL IT BE POSSIBLE
```

I have a node js API which return a value(not json type):

> res.send(code);

in reactjs i am   using fetch api in the following way,

```
  const options = {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"

  },
  body: JSON.stringify({ url: this.state.url })
};

fetch("http://localhost:3000/messages", options)
  .then(response => response)
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data)
    this.setState({ code: data.code });
  });
```

but i am getting an error as

> localhost/:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token h in
>   JSON at position 0

i know  i am getting this error as i am not passing json from the api can u help me solve this error
   the code in node api

```
        const express = require("express");
          const app = express();
         const cors = require("cors");
            const shorten = require("../../task1/src/shorten");
          const fs = require("fs");
           app.use(cors()); // to send CORS headers.
             app.use(express.urlencoded()); 
            app.use(express.json()); // to support JSON-encoded bodies.
           const fileName = "urldata.json";

             var write = (shortcode, urlData, url) => {
                 console.log(shortcode + ":::in writing");
                var shortcode = shortcode;
                  urlData.urlcodes.push({
                          url: url,
                      shorten: shortcode
                            });

           fs.writeFileSync(fileName, JSON.stringify(urlData), (err, data) 
        => {
          if (err) console.log(err);
          console.log("written in bdy");
             });
             };

                  var filecheck = (urlData, url, shrtcd) => {
                   {
             if (!shrtcd) {
  shortcode = shorten(url);
  write(shortcode, urlData, url);
  return shortcode;
     } else {
  write(shrtcd, urlData, url);

  return shrtcd;
        }
      }

          for (var i = 0; i < urlData["urlcodes"].length; i++) {
if (urlData["urlcodes"][i].url === url) {
  shortcode = urlData["urlcodes"][i].shorten;
  return shortcode;
            } else continue;
            }
         };

       app.post("/shortcodes", function(req, res) {

          console.log(req.body)
              if (!fs.existsSync(fileName)) {
                 const data = { urlcodes: [] };
                fs.createWriteStream(fileName, "utf-8");
                  fs.writeFile(fileName, JSON.stringify(data), err => {
                        console.log(err);
                       });
                          }
             fs.readFile(fileName, "utf-8", (err, data) => {
                if (err) console.log(err);
              var urlData = JSON.parse(data);

              var code = filecheck(urlData, req.body.url, req.body.shortcode);

          res.send(code); 
                });
               });
```

Comment: What is the value of `this.state.url` ?

Comment: Its a string which will be sent back from nodejs api

Comment: @VenuChinna see my edited Answer

Comment: Can i get your mail id ?

Answer (score 1):

Please modify your header:

```
{headers: {"Content-Type": "text/plain"}}
```

for parsing nested objects in req body you need to do something like this:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

This would solve the issue. Let me know if it doesn't work

Comment: @SteveArcher he is trying to post the data. To my understanding it's an issue with sending the data

Comment: No the body data is not going if i kept it as text/plain

Comment: If i use text/plain the data is not posting i mean not receiving in the api req.body

Comment: const options = {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "text/plain"

  },
  body: url: this.state.url 
} i am sending this way

Comment: Uncaught promise typeError failed to fetch this was the error i get if i send that way

Comment: wait what is your console.log(data) output ?

Comment: i am getting undefined

Comment: what is the required request payload?

Comment: i am not able to receive the url in req.body also

Comment: you meant this.state.url is undefined ?

Comment: have you added body parser there ? and to my understanding your post request was sent successfully

Comment: yes but i am not able access the url in backend(node api)

Comment: please share server.js and routes handing file

Answer (score 1):

```
"Content-Type": "application/json"
```

This is used for content-negotiation between client & server. This tells server if you are sending the JSON and accepting the response in the same format.

Now as you are asking for json negotiation so the server will try to parse the body as json and process the same.

In your case, you body data which you are sending is not valid JSON properly.

I would suggest you to log the body value and validate it with json validator (https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) and fix the changes suggested by the tool and try again.

Changing content-Type will not help till your server support it.

I hope it helps.